# Static readonly member assignation => TypeError: XXX is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, typeerror

I'm facing an issue with Typescript/Jest with static readonly member. Here a basic example.

The project structure is based on this starter project : https://github.com/alexjoverm/typescript-library-starter if it can help to reproduce issue.

**point.ts**

```
import {PointUtil} from "./pointUtil";

export class Point
{
    public x: number;
    public y: number;

    public constructor(x: number, y: number)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public dummyCalc() : number
    {
        return this.x + this.y + PointUtil.origin.x + PointUtil.origin.y;
    }
}
```

**pointutil.ts**

```
import {Point} from "./point";

export class PointUtil {
    public static readonly origin: Point = new Point(12, 2);
}
```

**repl.test.ts**

```
import {Point} from "../src/point";

describe("REPL test", () => {
    it("dummy test", () => {
        expect(new Point(1, 1).dummyCalc()).toEqual(16)
    });
});
```

**Error**

When run the test suite I'm getting

```
● Test suite failed to run

TypeError: _point.Point is not a constructor

  3 | export class PointUtil {
  4 |   public static readonly origin: Point = new Point(12, 2);
> 5 | }
  6 | 

  at src/pointUtil.ts:5:24
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/pointUtil.ts:7:2)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/point.ts:1:4237)
  at Object.<anonymous> (test/repl.test.ts:1:1181)
```

What does this error mean?

- Typescript version is 2.7.2
- jest 22.0.2
- ts-jest 22.0.0

Comment: Did the solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

The error is easier to understand if you add a console log to `pointutil.ts`:

```
import {Point} from "./point";

console.log('Point:', Point);

export class PointUtil {
    public static readonly origin: Point = new Point(12, 2);
}
```

This shows that `Point` is `undefined` (which is not a constructor :-) The reason this happens is that `point.ts` and `pointUtil.ts` import each other and create a circular module dependency. It is not related to the test, as the error would be triggered by any module that imports `point.ts`.

When module `point.ts` is evaluated, and it triggers the evaluation of `pointUtil.ts`, the value of the imported `Point` in `pointUtil.ts` will be undefined until the evaluation of the `point.ts` module has finished. However, since the definition of the static `origin` property amounts to doing

```
PointUtil.origin = new Point(12, 2);
```

it means that `Point` gets used before `pointUtil.ts` (and hence `point.ts`) have been evaluated, leading to the error.

Module `point.ts` also uses an import from `pointUtil.ts`, but this is inside the `dummyCalc` method, so it isn't evaluated during the initial module evaluation. This means that if you import `pointUtil.ts` before `point.ts` in `repl.test.ts`, the evaluation order of `point.ts` and `pointUtil.ts` is reversed, and the error will go away, since `point.ts` won't fail on an initially undefined `PointUtil`.

```
import './pointUtil'
import {Point} from './point'

describe("REPL test", () => {
  ..
});
```

This is a hacky solution though, so it is better to avoid the cycle and put definitions that immediately require `Point` in the `point.ts` module itself. As a matter of fact, `origin` is more suitable as a static property on `Point` anyway.